# Custom Post Type Archive in Sub Folder

Tags: directory, custom-post-type-archives

I have a sub-directory in my Wordpress theme (there are a lot of pages and I want a more logical structure). I have a custom post type called "entry" but if I place the archive-entry.php template in my sub-directory it is no longer picked up by the theme.

Is there a way I can put my custom post type archive templates in a sub-directory?

Comment: No.  [WordPress Template Heirarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike page templates, WordPress doesn't look in subdirectories for post template pages. The base function used for locating such templates is `locate_template()` (see [source](http://queryposts.com/function/locate_template/)), which looks in the root directory of your theme (and parent theme).

*(On the other hand `get_page_templates()` searches sub-directory)*.

You can use `template_include` filter (which filters the absolute path to your template) to change the template used:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse119820_use_different_template' );
function wpse119820_use_different_template( $template ){

   if( is_post_type_archive( 'entry' ) ){
       //"Entry" Post type archive. Find template in sub-dir. Look in child then parent theme

       if( $_template = locate_template( 'my-sub-dir/archive-entry.php' ) ){
            //Template found, - use that
            $template = $_template;
       }
   }            


   return $template;
}
```

Comment: Strange, I thought I tried this! Anyway this works for me now. Thanks!

Comment: Minor performance note: `template_include` fires AFTER WordPress has already gone through the trouble of trying to locate the template file. So I wouldn't recommend doing this if it's just to make your folders pretty.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @StephenHarris, the template loader does not do this by default.

While Stephen's answer looks fine to me, I was working on one before he posted and it is a bit different. I used the `archive_template` hook and generated the template name using `get_queried_object`.

```
add_action(
  'archive_template',
  function($template) {
    $path = pathinfo($template);
    if (!empty($path['filename'] && 'archive' === $path['filename']) {
      $pg = get_queried_object();
      if (!empty($pg->name)) {
        $t = locate_template('archive/'.$pg->name.'.php');
        if (!empty($t)) {
          $template = $t;
        }
      }
    }
    return $template;
  }
);
```

It is rough code. It may be buggy.